# USB mouse vs. Bluetooth mouse -- less battery drain

Tags: laptop, bluetooth, mice, battery

Which would drain a laptop battery less, a USB (LED) mouse or a bluetooth mouse? Nothing fancy, just a basic travel 3 button mouse in each case.

Comment: Probably usb. The actual transmit power of the bluetooth is very low. But I am not 100% sure. Measure it with an usb amp meter device ($5 or less) and with an usb bluetooth adapter.

Answer (score 2):

Let compare electric components.

I. The bluetooth is  controller + bt.
The WT12-A-AI5 (I found the datasheet) current is 31,5mA (Data transmitted @ 115200bps) * 3,6v. The power is 0,012 watt (max)

II. The wire mouse power.

The wire mouse is - 1.controller + 2.camera + 3.led.

1. The USB controller power do not know. I think the controller power can be ignored.
2. The camera is ADNS-2610 15mА*5V = 0,075 watt
3. The led power BL-B51V1 is 3,3v* 10mA = 0,033 watt

Also ADNS-2700 is full-mouse 35ma*5V+0,03watt = 0,2 watt.

Totally mouse power can not be less then 0,1 watt.

See also http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/how-much-power-does-a-wireless-mouse-use

A wired mouse power typically 0,1 - 0,2 Watt.

---

All ok, the wired mouse is more powerfull then bluetooth module (separettly).

Let compare with the notebook.

Typically a laptop 15`` has a 48 W*h battery and 2 hower of work. It's mean that a notebook power is 24 watt.

See: 0,1 watt of 24 watt is 0,4% of total power.
The 2 hower * 0,4% is approximately 30 seconds (0,1 watt) or 60 seconds 0,2 watt mouse.

---

Сonclusions:

- А laptop without a mouse will run 30-60 seconds longer.
- А laptop with a bluetooth mouse will run 26-50 seconds longer than wired mouse
  (The result may not be exactly the same, but the ratio of the values will be similar.)

You can take the power of the battery and the number of hours, substitute and estimate the number of seconds for your case. I think the result will be no more than 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking of a USB mouse with a cable that plugs into a USB port, not a wireless mouse with an RF dongle. If I were to use such a mouse, I'd turn Bluetooth off. The question is would a cable-connected USB mouse that got its power via the USB port drain the battery less than a Bluetooth mouse. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that the USB mouse has to power an *extra* transmitter. If Bluetooth is turned on *anyway*, then your laptop is powering *two* RF devices, so using just Bluetooth would be somewhat more efficient.

However, if you've actually turned off Bluetooth communication, then there would be little difference in power used between an external USB RF dongle and the internal Bluetooth device.

**However, both those RF devices use little power** compared to the laptop CPU, SSD or HHD, RAM and LCD backlight. The [Bluetooth specifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth) show *maximum* power allowed is 100 mW, and when operating short-range (1 m), the power used might be 1 mW. That is probably between 1/100 and 1/10,000 the power used by the CPU alone. Likely, you'd not be able to measure the difference in battery usage with *any* type of RF mouse.

High-power RF devices, such as [cellular modems](https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/cellular-modem), do consume more power, because the signal must reach a tower hundreds of meters distant. A WiFi adapter uses less power than a cellular modem, but it must still have a range of tens of meters, so turning off WiFi or reducing its range can extend run time.